# warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'SIZE_T' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, types, warnings

I need to have a set of overloaded functions in my code but I get convertion wanrings.
Here is a test code:

```
#include windows.h

void f(DWORD arg){...}

//void f(SIZE_T arg){}

void main(void)
{
DWORD dword=0;
SIZE_T size_t=dword;
f(size_t);

}
```

The compiler gives warning:

```
test.cpp(11) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'SIZE_T' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data
```

If I uncomment void f(SIZE_T arg) I get

```
test.cpp(5) : error C2084: function 'void f(DWORD)' already has a body
```

How can I avoid having this warning or error?

Answer (score 15):

`size_t` is guaranteed to be an unsigned integral type, but the number of bits it has isn't specified.  It could be equal to a `DWORD` (32 bits), or it could be 64 bits on a 64-bit platform.  For maximal portability, you shouldn't assume it has a certain number of bits, which is what the compiler is warning you about.  If you know your value will never exceed 2^32 (which is a reasonable assumption in 99.99% of cases), then you can just cast to a `DWORD` to get rid of the warning:

```
SIZE_T sz = dword;
f((DWORD)sz);  // no warning here
```

The error you're getting is because in your case, `size_t` is actually 32 bits, and so the function signatures of your two `f` functions are identical - they both take a single unsigned 32-bit parameter.  You'll have to use separate names for them in order to guarantee that your program is portable between 32- and 64-bit platforms:

```
void f_DWORD(DWORD arg) { ... }
void f_size_t(size_t arg) { ... }
```

One final note: `size_t` is a built-in type.  `SIZE_T` is non-standard and is almost definitely a typedef or a #define for `size_t`.  You should use `size_t` instead of `SIZE_T`, and you should also avoid naming your variables `size_t`, since that introduces confusion by shadowing a type name with a variable name.

Comment: Hi, I came to this question with a deeper doubt. What should be done in such cases? When you have to convert between such types what is the ideal way, without making any assumptions about the sizes of each? so that code works in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to get rid of `f(DWORD)` and redefine it `f(size_t)`.  Unless, of course, `f()` operates on values other than `size_t`s.

Answer (score -2):

SIZE_T takes 8 bytes in 64bit system while DWORD takes 4 bytes

from [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;

#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
#endif
```

Comment: Careful! `size_t` and `SIZE_T` are two different things. What does your answer add to the existing ones from 8 years ago? I can't see it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I encountered the same problem and solved it right now. I can do better than other answers. typedef unsigned int   size_t; (from <SourceAnnotations.h>).  and size_t and SIZE_T are same in windows.

Comment: If you can do better than the other answers then by all means go ahead, but you haven't so far. And, no, `size_t` and `SIZE_T` are not defined to be the same in Windows (read the documentation page you linked to) even though they may appear to match up in your implementation.